# iOS - Linker Error, Duplicate Symbol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, linker, duplicates

It seems I am having an error when attempting to compile and it seems to be pointing to two files directly..MenuViewController and FirstTopViewController. I think it has something to do with my imports, as each of them is importing the other, however the error is referencing my Building object, which is barely used in it. Also, with the clang error, how do I use -v to see the invocation?

Error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Building in /Users/alexmuller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECSlidingViewController-gjxwxiwumgohyehiawnlamggzmop/Build/Intermediates/ECSlidingViewController.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECSlidingViewController.build/Objects-normal/i386/FirstTopViewController.o and /Users/alexmuller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ECSlidingViewController-gjxwxiwumgohyehiawnlamggzmop/Build/Intermediates/ECSlidingViewController.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ECSlidingViewController.build/Objects-normal/i386/MenuViewController.o for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

FirstTopViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "TimesViewController.h"
#import "BuildingViewController.h"
#import "BuildingAnnotation.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@class BuildingViewController;

@interface FirstTopViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet MKMapView *_map;
    BuildingViewController *buildingVC;
    BuildingAnnotation *buildAnnotation;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) MKMapView *map;

- (IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)revealTimes:(id)sender;
- (void)loadBuilding:(Building *)building;

@end
```

FirstTopViewController.m

```
#import "FirstTopViewController.h"

@implementation FirstTopViewController

@synthesize map = _map;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    buildingVC = (BuildingViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BuildingList"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [(UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:10] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RedWithNoise"]]];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:204.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], 
      UITextAttributeTextColor, 
      [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8], 
      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
      [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], 
      UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"AGaramondPro-Regular" size:23.0], 
      UITextAttributeFont, 
      nil]];
    self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
    self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.layer.bounds].CGPath;
    self.view.clipsToBounds = NO;

    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(30.451667, -84.268533), 16090.344, 16090.344);
    viewRegion = [_map regionThatFits:viewRegion];
    [_map setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];

    if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
    }

    if (![self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController isKindOfClass:[TimesViewController class]]) {
        self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Times"];
    }

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];


}

- (void)loadBuilding:(Building *)building {
    if (buildingVC.buildingSelected) {
        if (buildAnnotation != nil) {
            [_map removeAnnotation:buildAnnotation];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", building.getName);
        buildAnnotation = [[BuildingAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:building.getLocation.coordinate withName:building.getName withAddress:building.getAddress];
        [_map setCenterCoordinate:buildAnnotation.coordinate animated:YES];
        [_map addAnnotation:buildAnnotation];
    }
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
  self.view.layer.shadowPath = nil;
  self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
  self.view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.layer.bounds].CGPath;
  self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = NO;
}

- (IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender
{
  [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight];
}

- (IBAction)revealTimes:(id)sender {
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECLeft];
}

@end
```

MenuViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import "FirstTopViewController.h"
#import "TimesViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndex;
}

@end
```

MenuViewController.m

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"

typedef enum {
    ENGINEERING,
    GARNET,
    GOLD,
    HERITAGE,
    NIGHT,
    OSCEOLA,
    RENEGADE,
    TOMAHAWK
} RouteName;


@interface MenuViewController()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *menuItems;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *optionItems;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrayItems;

- (UIImage *)determineActiveRoute:(RouteName)route;
@end

@implementation MenuViewController
@synthesize menuItems, optionItems, arrayItems;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{

    self.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Engineering", @"Garnet", @"Gold", @"Heritage Grove", @"Night Nole", @"Osceola", @"Renegade", @"Tomahawk", nil];
    self.optionItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Buildings", @"Directions", nil];
    self.arrayItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.menuItems, self.optionItems, nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:200.0f];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
  return [[self.arrayItems objectAtIndex:sectionIndex] count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.arrayItems count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 35;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *sectionView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [sectionView sizeToFit];
    sectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navCellDivider"]];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 20)];
    label.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AGaramondPro-Regular" size:12.0];
    if(section == 0)
        label.text = @"BUS ROUTES";
    else
        label.text = @"OTHER OPTIONS";
    [sectionView addSubview:label];
    return sectionView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UILabel *label;
    UIImageView *imageView;
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuItemCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }
    UIView *selectedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    selectedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navCellBackgroundSelected"]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navCellBackground"]];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AGaramondPro-Regular" size:15.0];
    label.text = [[self.arrayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        [imageView setImage:[self determineActiveRoute:indexPath.row]];
    } else {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"building"]];
        } else {
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"60-signpost"]];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /* Type cast view as a First Top to make it easier to read. Do switch to select correct route,
        then modify map afterwards to load up correct route.
     TimesViewController can be set to the corresponding times when selected
     */
    FirstTopViewController *mapViewController = (FirstTopViewController *)self.slidingViewController.topViewController;
    TimesViewController *timesViewController = (TimesViewController *)self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        selectedIndex = indexPath;
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case ENGINEERING:
                NSLog(@"Engineering Selected\n");
                timesViewController.times.text = @"Engineering";
                break;
            case GARNET:
                NSLog(@"Garnet Selected\n");
                timesViewController.times.text = @"Garnet";
                break;
            case GOLD:
                NSLog(@"Gold Selected\n");
                timesViewController.times.text = @"Gold";
                break;
            case HERITAGE:
                NSLog(@"Heritage Grove Selected\n");
                timesViewController.times.text = @"Heritage Grove";
                break;
            case NIGHT:
                NSLog(@"Night Nole Selected\n");
                timesViewController.times.text = @"Night Nole";
                break;
            case OSCEOLA:
                NSLog(@"Osceola Selected\n");
                timesViewController.times.text = @"Osceola";
                break;
            case RENEGADE:
                NSLog(@"Renegade Selected\n");
                timesViewController.times.text = @"Renegade";
                break;
            case TOMAHAWK:
                NSLog(@"Tomahawk Selected\n");
                timesViewController.times.text = @"Tomahawk";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } else {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            BuildingViewController *buildings = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BuildingList"];
            buildings.userLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:mapViewController.map.userLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:mapViewController.map.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];

            [self presentModalViewController:buildings animated:YES];
        }
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndex animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight animations:nil onComplete:^{
        [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
    }];
}

- (UIImage *)determineActiveRoute:(RouteName)route {
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalender components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    switch (route) {
        case ENGINEERING:
            if ([components day] % 7 == 2) {
                if (([components hour] >= 7) && ([components hour] < 17)) {
                    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"green"];
                } else {
                    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"red"];
                }
            } else if (([components day] % 7 == 3) || ([components day] % 7 == 4)) {
                return [UIImage imageNamed:@"red"];
            } else {
                //Weekday
                if (([components hour] >= 7) && ([components hour] < 19)) {
                    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"green"];
                } else {
                    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"red"];
                }
            }
            break;
        case GARNET:
        case GOLD:
        case HERITAGE:
            if ((([components day] % 7 <= 3) || ([components day] % 7 >= 5)) &&
                (([components hour] >= 7) && ([components hour] <= 19))) {
                return [UIImage imageNamed:@"green"];
            } else {
                return [UIImage imageNamed:@"red"];
            }
            break;
        case NIGHT:
            if ((([components day] % 7 == 6) || ([components day] % 7 <= 3)) &&
                (([components hour] >= 22.5) || ([components hour] <= 3))) {
                return [UIImage imageNamed:@"green"];
            } else {
                return [UIImage imageNamed:@"red"];
            }
            break;
        case OSCEOLA:
        case RENEGADE:
        case TOMAHAWK:
            if ((([components day] % 7 <= 3) || ([components day] % 7 >= 5)) &&
                (([components hour] >= 7) && ([components hour] <= 19))) {
                return [UIImage imageNamed:@"green"];
            } else {
                return [UIImage imageNamed:@"red"];
            }
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Duplicate symbols means that you have two classes both named 'Builder' in your project, or compile list.

Comment: I have Building.h, BuildingAnnotation.h, and BuildingViewController.m/h. Is there a way to clear the compile list and have Xcode regenerate it?

Comment: Clear your compile list, then when you go to add everything back, search for the term ".m" (without quotes), and highlight every .m file.  then click add.

Comment: Where is this "compile list"? Are you referring to the Compile Sources under Build Phases?

Comment: Why are you using .c as an extension instead of .m ?

Comment: It is .m, I just had a brain fart, let me go ahead and change that..

Comment: @Muller that's exactly what I was referring to.  As for Thomas's comment, I would address that first.

Comment: @CodaFi that fixed it, I really appreciate your help. If you want to add a real answer, I will more that happily give you the credit you deserve.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per your request :

Remove all of your classes from compile sources, then click the + button and search for the term '.m'.  Highlight every class, then click add.  Build and run again.

Comment: iAnum check that you @implementation line has the correct name

Comment: I was able to go into compile sources to the specific file that was complaining about duplicate symbols. Removed it and re-added it and it worked. Essentially the same as this answer without bombing the entire thing.

Answer (score 26):

Check that you have not imported the .m file where it should be the .h file. Doh!

Comment: amazing! I was going crazy and never would have looked closely enough for this

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error when importing third party library with multiple *.a files to my IOS project.
In my case removing ‘-all_load’ linker flag solved the problem.

Comment: This got rid of most of my duplicates. Still have 4 left.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but there are a couple of things that it could be.

1. I notice that neither class appears to import Building.h so my first thought is that the compiler doesn't know where to get the info for this class. DO you need to add an #import?
2. The next thing was that I generally try to avoid having two classes which import each other. The compile might have problems trying to work out what order to compile them in. You might need to change one of them to use `@class ...` rather than `#import ...` so that the compiler leaves it until runtime to resolve the class.
3. Finally have you done a clean? Some times when refactoring a lot, old class definitions get left in the build directories and can cause problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the file and choose "Remove Reference". Drag the file back again to the project and it should be ok. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that was causing this for me was that I had duplicated an m file, but not renamed the @implementation. Make sure that you don't have duplicate @implementation declarations.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem, because both `ICMGameDemo` and `CMGameSDK` added that **.m** file into the `compile sources` panel, I drop the `ICMGameDemo`'s and re-build the problem gone.

[image: project settings screenshot]